# how to combine 2 functions javascript of datatables

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

i also got error
DataTables warning: table id=example - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3

this is my code

i also got error
DataTables warning: table id=example - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3

this is my code

first javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   //fungsi untuk filtering data berdasarkan tanggal
   var start_date;
   var end_date;
   var DateFilterFunction = (function (oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
      var dateStart = parseDateValue(start_date);
      var dateEnd = parseDateValue(end_date);
      //Kolom tanggal yang akan kita gunakan berada dalam urutan 2, karena dihitung mulai dari 0
      //nama depan = 0
      //nama belakang = 1
      //tanggal terdaftar =2
      var evalDate= parseDateValue(aData[2]);
        if ( ( isNaN( dateStart ) && isNaN( dateEnd ) ) ||
             ( isNaN( dateStart ) && evalDate <= dateEnd ) ||
             ( dateStart <= evalDate && isNaN( dateEnd ) ) ||
             ( dateStart <= evalDate && evalDate <= dateEnd ) )
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
  });
 
  // fungsi untuk converting format tanggal dd/mm/yyyy menjadi format tanggal javascript menggunakan zona aktubrowser
  function parseDateValue(rawDate) {
      var dateArray= rawDate.split("/");
      var parsedDate= new Date(dateArray[2], parseInt(dateArray[1])-1, dateArray[0]);  // -1 because months are from 0 to 11  
      return parsedDate;
  }   
 
  $( document ).ready(function() {
  //konfigurasi DataTable pada tabel dengan id example dan menambahkan  div class dateseacrhbox dengan dom untuk meletakkan inputan daterangepicker
   var $dTable = $('#example').DataTable({
    "dom": "<'row'<'col-sm-4'l><'col-sm-5' <'datesearchbox'>><'col-sm-3'f>>" +
      "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
      "<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>"
   });
 
 
   //menambahkan daterangepicker di dalam datatables
   $("div.datesearchbox").html('<div class="input-group"> <div class="input-group-addon"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i> </div><input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="datesearch" placeholder="Search by date range.."> </div>');
 
   document.getElementsByClassName("datesearchbox")[0].style.textAlign = "right";
 
   //konfigurasi daterangepicker pada input dengan id datesearch
   $('#datesearch').daterangepicker({
      autoUpdateInput: false
    });
 
   //menangani proses saat apply date range
    $('#datesearch').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
       $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
       start_date=picker.startDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY');
       end_date=picker.endDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY');
       $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(DateFilterFunction);
       $dTable.draw();
    });
 
    $('#datesearch').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
      $(this).val('');
      start_date='';
      end_date='';
      $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.splice($.fn.dataTable.ext.search.indexOf(DateFilterFunction, 1));
      $dTable.draw();
    });
  });
```

Second javascript

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
            var api = this.api();
  
            // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
            var intVal = function ( i ) {
                return typeof i === 'string' ?
                    i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                    typeof i === 'number' ?
                        i : 0;
            };
  
            // Total over all pages
            total = api
                .column( 4 )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );
  
            // Total over this page
            pageTotal = api
                .column( 4, { page: 'current'} )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );
  
                $(api.column(4).footer()).html(this.fnSettings().fnFormatNumber( 'Rp ' +pageTotal));
            // Update footer
            // $( api.column( 4 ).footer() ).html(
            //     'Rp '+pageTotal +' '
            // );
        }
    } );
} );
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in the link you posted, you cannot initialize twice a DataTable instance on the same HTML node.

You're trying to do exactly this, as you're calling DataTable() on the `#example` node twice (the first one passing in the **'dom'** initialization option, the second one passing in the **footerCallback** initialization option).

Simply, pass them **togheter** in one single initialization call:

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    "dom": // dom code,
    "footerCallback": function  ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
        // code
    }
})
```

Comment: can u please write full code to combine ?